# Is it possible to add additional properties to a .settings file in C# (.NET Framework 4.7.2)

Tags: c#, settings, visual-studio-2019, .net-4.7.2

I am developing an application using C# in .NET Framework 4.7.2.  Originally I had some data that I thought would be useful to use .ini files for configuration purposes.  I learned rather quickly that .ini files are out of vogue in .NET and that it would be prudent to use configuration files.  That is, .settings files.

For some context for my application, these configuration data would refer to PLC program tag names that could be added/removed rather easily by a programmer without needing to expose the C# application (ie. If we wanted to add a tag to be read by our application, we can easily add it to the configuration file and the string value would be parsed by our Tag-Reading Extension).

What I have done is create a number of .settings files to allow for an easier way for me to organize the scope of certain blocks of tags.  It may not be the most efficient way to do this but it works for me at the moment to do proof of concept.  I may change this later but right now I'd like to keep it as is.

My question relates to how these .settings files work and if they are configurable themselves.

[image: Screencap]

In the picture above, I see four headers.  I've been calling them properties: "Name", "Type", "Scope", and "Value".  I am able to refer to any of these properties using the SettingsProperty class (I think is this the correct classification for this object).  In a few very specific cases I need to supply an additional property to a tag to give it special attention.  Is this something possible in C# visual studio 2019 and if so, could someone please point me in the right direction to achieve this?  I thought about perhaps using a List of Strings instead but would prefer from a usability standpoint to not do it this way if there is a way around that I simply haven't found yet.  I haven't been successful in searching for how/if this is done or if this is even an appropriate way to solve this problem.

In short, in addition to "Name", "Type", "Scope" and "Value", I would like to add "TagType" (of type string) which I can set and get as needed from within my .settings files.

Thank you very much for any insight that can be offered!

EDIT: Typos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea that you can store both value and TagType into `Column Value`. And use any one character to separate them, such as `|`.

[image]

Then you can access them by splitting the string.

```
string value = Properties.Settings.Default.Tag_1.Split('|')[0].Trim();
string tagtype = Properties.Settings.Default.Tag_1.Split('|')[1].Trim();
Console.WriteLine($"Value = {value}, TagType = {tagtype}");
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: I'll give this a try and let you know how it works!  Thank you for your insight!